# Много Appdomain приложения: ограничения и производительность

Tags: c#

Если какое-то ограничение по количеству доменов в приложении?
Сильно ли будит нагружено приложение если будут создаваться, использоваться и далее unload новые домены?

P.S на доменах у меня реализована система плагинов (Дабы при изменения данных в плагине(dll) можно было загрузить новую dll с правками за место старой)

Comment: Вроде можно неограниченное количество (в каких-то там больших приделах), но на производительность влияет, так что надо с осторожностью.

Comment: ну а если делать unload ненужных доменов?или они будут висеть до выгрузки самого приложения

Comment: Мое мнение, что доменами можно полноценно оперировать только из собственного лоадера, который по COM интерфейсу подымает CLR домены, из него можно их гарантированно очистить. Из самой апликухи на С# в очистке не уверен, даже скорее наоборот, уверен в обратном.

Comment: Просто я плагины dll хочу сделать под игровой сервер - чтобы код изменил и загрузил обновленный

Comment: Игровой сервер на движке unity

Comment: Домены для этих целей перебор, на мой взгляд, посмотрите MEH. Проведите эксперимент, поднимите 100 доменов, посмотрите память, удалите 100 доменов, посмотрите память :)

Comment: Что за МЕН?можно ссылочку?

Comment: Описался, MEF https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/

Comment: К сожелению я использую net 3.5 из за ограничений старого движка

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, ограничений на количество доменов приложений нет ни в .NET, ни в Mono (кроме доступной в системе памяти, разумеется).

Что касается производительности. Домены приложений предоставляют полную изоляцию: код из одного домена не может напрямую обратиться к памяти из другого домена. Вместо этого, либо объекты сериализуются и передаются через границы доменов по значению, либо все вызовы с использованием объекта проксируются через Remoting (один из видов межпроцессного взаимодействия). И то и другое - серьезные накладные расходы, это да. Но альтернативы нет: поддержка выгрузки сборок из основного домена появилась только в [.NET Core 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#assembly-unloadability) , а создание нового процесса под плагин даст еще большие накладные расходы. Поэтому трудно сказать, "Сильно ли будит нагружено": непонятно, с чем сравнивать.

Comment: а возможно ли полностью выгрузить dll из процесса?я сделал такое на mono, но после правок при загрузки загружается dll без правок (первоначальная)

Comment: @MeshBenth выгрузить dll (управляемую) в .NET Framework / Mono нельзя. Можно выгрузить домен приложений, это выгрузит все dll, которые в него загружены (если они не используются также другим доменом)

Comment: но а как же https://github.com/warbler/SharpMonoInjector

Comment: @MeshBenth Если DLL загружена как неуправляемая, то да, выгрузка возможна. Но эта утилита - главным образом для внедрения своего кода в чужие приложения, для разработки своей системы плагинов решение с WriteProcessMemory/CreateRemoteThread выглядит не очень подходящим. Кроме того, это полностью завязано на Windows API.